# Design JavaFX custom control with dynamic data

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, custom-controls

I'm trying to create my own control in JavaFX.
My problem is that my control is not static (e.g. label, button...) but dynamic (e.g. ListView), so new records are constantly added and removed.
I'm not sure how to implement it in JavaFX, so to get a feel for it I want to recreate a control similar to ListView.
In the following I have written a small example.

- **MyList**
  The actual control similar to ListView.
- **MyListItem**
  An object stored in MyList that contains only one string to be displayed.
- **MyListSkin**
  The skin responsible for the graphical representation.

The example works as it should, but it feels a bit dirty.
To keep everything small and simple I don't want to use CSS and FXML.

**How can I implement this cleaner, especially with regard to more complex situations?**

- How keep data, logic and graphics separated?

  - Should I use BehaviorBase and if so how?
- How keep track of MyListItem objects and their corresponding graphical representation/nodes?

  - How should I handle initialization?
  - How to keep them synchronized?

[image: Example application screenshot.]

**MyList.java**

```
public class MyList extends Control
{
    private ListProperty<MyListItem> mItems;

    public MyList()
    {
        mItems = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() 
    {
        return new MyListSkin(this);
    }

    public ObservableList<MyListItem> getItems()
    {
        return mItems.get();
    }

    public void setItems(ObservableList<MyListItem> pItems)
    {
        mItems.set(pItems);
    }

    public ListProperty<MyListItem> itemsProperty()
    {
        return mItems;
    }
}
```

**MyListItem.java**

```
public class MyListItem 
{
    private StringProperty mName;


    public MyListItem(String pName)
    {
        mName = new SimpleStringProperty(pName);
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return mName.get();
    }

    public void setName(String pName)
    {
        mName.set(pName);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

**MyListSkin.java**

```
public class MyListSkin extends SkinBase<MyList>
{
    private VBox mVBox;
    private Map<MyListItem, Label> mNodes;

    protected MyListSkin(MyList pControl)
    {
        super(pControl);

        mVBox = new VBox();
        mNodes = new HashMap<>();

        getChildren().add(mVBox);

        getSkinnable().getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<MyListItem>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends MyListItem> pChange)
            {
                removeItems(pChange.getRemoved());
                addItems(pChange.getAddedSubList());
            }
        });

        getSkinnable().itemsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ObservableList<MyListItem>>() 
        {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<MyListItem>> pObservable,
                    ObservableList<MyListItem> pOldValue, ObservableList<MyListItem> pNewValue) 
            {
                clearItems();
                addItems(pNewValue);
            }
        });

        addItems(getSkinnable().getItems());
    }

    private void addItems(List<? extends MyListItem> list)
    {
        for(MyListItem lItem : list)
        {
            Label lLabel = new Label();
            lLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            lLabel.setPrefWidth(200);
            lLabel.textProperty().bind(lItem.nameProperty());
            mVBox.getChildren().add(lLabel);
            mNodes.put(lItem, lLabel);
        }
    }

    private void removeItems(List<? extends MyListItem> list)
    {
        for(MyListItem lItem : list)
        {
            mVBox.getChildren().remove(mNodes.get(lItem));
            mNodes.remove(lItem);
        }
    }

    private void clearItems()
    {
        for(Map.Entry<MyListItem, Label> lEntry : mNodes.entrySet())
        {
            mVBox.getChildren().remove(lEntry.getValue());
            mNodes.remove(lEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage pPrimaryStage)
    {
        MyList lControl = new MyList();
        lControl.getItems().add(new MyListItem("Test 1"));
        lControl.getItems().add(new MyListItem("Test 2"));
        lControl.getItems().add(new MyListItem("Test 3"));
        lControl.getItems().add(new MyListItem("Test 4"));

        Pane lRoot = new Pane();
        lRoot.getChildren().add(lControl);

        pPrimaryStage.setScene(new Scene(lRoot, 800, 800));
        pPrimaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] pArguments)
    {
        launch(pArguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ListView` is a _virtualized_ control. It only creates as many `ListCell`s as it needs to fill the display and then reuses them as you scroll. In Java 9+ the class that handles this became public API: [`javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html). In Java 8 you'll need (if you want to virtualize your own control) to use the internal version. You could also try to create your own implementation but looking at `VirtualFlow` that seems non-trivial (for Java 10 its a nearly 3,000 line file).

Answer (score 0):

> How to keep data, logic and graphics separated?

The separate classes do just that, `MyListItem` is your data, `MyList` is your logic, and `MyListSkin` is your graphics.

> > Should I use BehaviorBase and if so how?

Really up to you, if you want to then I recommend reading `ListViewBehavior` and possibly extending from it. Also check out `CellBehaviorBase` and its subclasses.

> How keep track of `MyListItem` objects and their corresponding graphical representation/nodes?

Not exactly sure what you're asking, keep track of them in your `Control` and keep track of the graphical representations in your `Skin`, which it seems like you're doing.

> > How should I handle initialization?

Seems fine how you're doing it.

> > How to keep them synchronized?

Same way you would keep anything else synchronized, listen for changes in the `Control` and update the `Skin` which it also looks like you're doing, does it not work?

---

If you want custom graphics for individual `Label`s in your list then you could handle it for some general cases through your `MyListSkin`, eg. setting a `PseudoClass` for even or odd indexed elements.